# pgfplots does not use declared marks at a table plot

Tags: pgfplots, plot

I use

```
\pgfdeclareplotmark{mymark}
  {\shade[draw=none,ball color=green!70] (0pt, 0pt) circle [radius=2pt];}
```

Why has `\addplot3 table [only marks, mark=mymark]` no effect? 
What have I to do?

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
%\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}

\pgfdeclareplotmark{mymark}
  {\shade[draw=none,ball color=green!70] (0pt, 0pt) circle [radius=2pt];}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\begin{axis}[]
\addplot3[variable=\t, mark=mymark]({t^2},{t},{-3}) node[pos=0.3,above]{marks good};; 

\addplot3 table [x=Y,y=X, z expr=0,  only marks, mark=mymark] {
X Y 
0 2
1 0
} node[right]{marks bad};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Common mistake: you've added the mark to the *table*. Try adding them to the *plot*. I.e. `\addplot [mark=mymark] table[x=...`

Comment: Oh my dear..... Thx....

Comment: @TorbjørnT., do you want to write an answer or shall we close the question as "solved in the comments"?

Comment: @StefanPinnow I've never liked that close reason, but I found a duplicate.